# Bash: append multiline string to a variable while preserving whitespace

Tags: bash, heredoc

I want to append a multiline string while preserving whitespace to an existing variable.

```
final_str='$one'
tmp=$(cat << 'EOM'

$two
$three
EOM
)
final_str=${final_str}${tmp}
echo $final_str
```

Output:

```
$one $two $three
```

Expected output:

```
$one 
$two 
$three
```

How do I achieve this using nowdoc? Are there any simpler ways to do this?

Comment: `echo $final_str` itself loses your whitespace even if it was perfectly preserved up to that point. Always, _always_ quote your expansions (as http://shellcheck.net/ instructs).

Comment: BTW, `final_str+="$tmp"` is somewhat faster to run.

Comment: ...anyhow, see https://ideone.com/D7t2yK demonstrating that the failure to quote the expansion on the `echo` command really is the entirety of the issue at hand.

Comment: "Are there any simpler ways to do this?" Yes by using an array. What exactly is your goal?